# How to assign $_GET value via 'a href'

Tags: php

This is what I've done so far, but the $_GET['c_id'] is not assigned (URL looks like this `http://localhost/srs_stuff.php?c_id=`
Results are surely stored in $r variable since c_name is normally displayed as clickable link with the name I want.

```
foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo "<a href='srs_stuff.php?c_id='" . $r['c_id'] . ">" . $r['c_name'] . "</a></br>";
}
```

Even better solution would be, that the c_id would be set in SESSION variable, before redirection to new page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  <a href='srs_stuff.php?c_id='" . $r['c_id']
> ```

HTML attribute values can be delimited by `"` or `'`. You are using `'`.

Your `href` value starts with `srs_` and goes on until the next `'`.

The next `'` is here `id='`: **before** the $r['c_id'] value.

Put your attribute delimiters in the right place (and use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), which would pick up errors like this).

---

Better yet, don't generate URLs by mashing strings together and then generating HTML by mashing more strings together.

```
<?php
    $query_string = http_build_query(c_id => $r['c_id']);
    $url = "srs_stuff.php?" . $query_string;
    $html_safe_url = htmlspecialchars($url);
    $html_safe_name = htmlspecialchars($r['c_name']);
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $html_safe_url; ?>">
        <?php echo $html_safe_name; ?>
    </a>
    <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing `href` attribute before assigning the value.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
$r['c_id'] = 234;
$r['c_name'] = 'Developer';
echo "<a href='srs_stuff.php?c_id=" . $r['c_id'] . "'>" . $r['c_name'] . "</a></br>";
?>
```

HTML output produced (source code):

```
<a href='srs_stuff.php?c_id=234'>Developer</a></br>
```